# qpdf warning: Cross-reference stream data has the wrong size

Tags: conversion, warnings, tools

I compile the following with `pdflatex` (pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian))

```
\pdfminorversion=5% With these lines...
\pdfobjcompresslevel=3% ... commented out...
\pdfcompresslevel=9% ... there is no warning from qpdf.

\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

bla

\end{document}
```

and run the qpdf on the resulting pdf `qpdf --linearize paper.pdf paper.linearized.pdf`, then I get the following warning:

> WARNING: uppsats.pdf (xref stream,
>   file position 9448): Cross-reference
>   stream data has the wrong size;
>   expected = 48; actual = 52
>
> qpdf: operation succeeded with
>   warnings; resulting file may have some
>   problems

Is there any way to avoid or fix this problem other than commenting out the first three lines?

Comment: Is there actually a problem? The warning says that the operation succeeded. Do you see problems in the resulting file? If so, what kind?

Comment: I cannot spot any problems in the file when viewing it. I'm wondering what the warning means. Is there problems with cross-references?

Comment: Can you clarify what (if any) connection this question has to TeX? It sounds off-topic.

Comment: Linearizing is a part of the process in preparing a document.

Comment: Is `paper.pdf` produced by TeX? If so, which compilation method do you use? (dvi->dvips->ps2pdf? pdftex? xetex? luatex? dvi->dvipdfm? etc). Does this warning happen *only* for TeX-produced PDFs? Does it happen with *all* TeX-produced PDFs or only some (in which case, include a minimal example so others can reproduce your issue)? Without any details it's impossible even to tell even whether this question is on-topic, let alone give any meaningful answer.

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the question so the warning should be reproducible.

Comment: I could not reproduce this. With your example I don't get any PDF produced at all. When I add some text between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` I get a PDF that qpdf linearizes without warnings. `pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.11-2.2 (TeX Live 2010)` and `qpdf version 2.1.2` in case that helps.

Comment: Oh, there has to be some text in the document for it to produce. I've changed the document example accordingly.

Comment: Still can't reproduce. Linearizes without warnings.

Comment: I'm using pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) if that matters. I just reproduced it on a new file to make sure it's not random.

Comment: It seems unlikely that a document without crossreferences would produce that error... Unless cross references doesn't mean what I think it means. I kind of assumed it would be related to hyperref or similar...

Comment: @Seamus: you assume wrongly :) The xref stream is kind of an index to the structures of the PDF. It contains information that permits random access to indirect objects within the file so that the entire file need not be read to locate any particular object. It is only present in PDF1.5 and later versions (before that there were xref tables), hence the `\pdfminorversion` connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that this was a bug in pdftex 1.40.10 (TL2009) that was fixed for 1.40.11 (TL2010) with svn revision 581. [Here's the svn diff.](http://foundry.supelec.fr/gf/project/pdftex/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2Ftags%2F1.40.11%2Fsource%2Fsrc%2Ftexk%2Fweb2c%2Fpdftexdir%2Fpdftex.web&root=pdftex&r1=580&r2=581&diff_format=u) Try updating to TL2010.

Comment: I updated to TeX Live 2011 and I no longer get the warning.